Dynamic url with Nuxt 3 SSR. Metadata seen in the browser are not seen in bots
I'm trying to do this with Nuxt 3 (SSR). I will use an SEO friendly url structure. Example;
Product;
abc.com/lace-up-sports-shoes
Category;
abc.com/shoes
Brand;
abc.com/bysho

I need to make a query to my API based on the request in the url. And the following response will come from the API;
type:product
related_id:23

This is a product. Redirect to pages/product.vue.
pages/product.vue page will make a request to the API and return the product information according to related_id. Afterwards, he will fill in the template section and add meta title, description og:title... information for the head.
I've done everything so far. But when I published my site, I noticed that the meta tags were loading slowly (it works correctly in the browser).
But when I test it on Facebook and similar applications, the platforms cannot receive data such as og:title, og:descriptions.
And so Google probably won't be able to index my site properly.
I've been researching on the internet for days, I've been chatting with gpt, I've tried every way.
But as a result, I was not successful in showing the meta data before the page started.
By the way, I set up my system as follows;
The [...slug].vue page asks the API for the incoming URL request.
According to the response from the API, it loads the product, category, brand components under the pages folder.
Components make a request from the API and pull the required product, category or brand.
Creating meta with useHead;
I tried it on [...slug] but it didn't work.
I tried product, category, brand .vue files, but it still didn't work.
Actually it does, but it is not created in a way that bots can see, but they are seen under the tag in the browser.

I tried all the methods that need to be tried for useHead.
In [...slug.vue], adding onMounted, asyncData, useHead as normal. But it didn't happen. According to the data coming from the API, when I add useHead, the content cannot be read by bots. When I write something static, there is no problem, bots can see the content.

This is my [...slug].vue component.
I pulled the product's data in this component and tried it with useHead, but it didn't work. Since I deleted the codes of that part, I did not recreate it.
<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="component" :content="content" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import urlRepository from '~/repositories/urlRepository';

import Product from '~/pages/Product.vue';
import Category from '~/pages/Category.vue';
import Brand from '~/pages/Brand.vue';
import Error from '~/components/Error.vue';

const route = useRoute();
const { locale, locales, t } = useI18n();


const content = ref({});
const component = shallowRef(null);

const loadContent = async (path) => {
  try {
    const data = await urlRepository().fetchUrl(path);
    if (!data) {
      component.value = Error;
      return;
    }
    const [componentName, relatedId] = data;
    await assignPage(componentName, relatedId);
  } catch (error) {
    component.value = Error;
  }
};

const assignPage = async (type, relatedId) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'product':
      component.value = Product;
      break;
    case 'category':
      component.value = Category;
      break;
    case 'brand':
      component.value = Brand;
      break;
    default:
      component.value = Error;
  }
  content.value = { relatedId };
};

onMounted(() => {
  const path = route.params.path[0];
  loadContent(path);
});

watch(() => route.params.path, (newPath) => {
  loadContent(newPath[0]);
});
</script>

